# How do we get this solution of the differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we get the following solution $$\overrightarrow{h}(t)=\underline{R}(t, \overrightarrow{\xi}(\overrightarrow{x}))\overrightarrow{h}(0)$$ (where $\underline{R}(t, \overrightarrow{\xi}(\overrightarrow{x}))$ is the rotation matrix as for $t$ around the axis $\overrightarrow{\xi}(\overrightarrow{x})$ at the positive direction)

of the differential equation $$\frac{d\overrightarrow{h}}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{\xi}(\overrightarrow{x}) \times \overrightarrow{h} \ \ , \ \  (\overrightarrow{x}=\text{ constant } )$$ ??

Comment: i don't know what  $R$ is.

Comment: It is the transformation matrix... @abel

Comment: what do you mean transformation matrix?

Comment: I meant rotation matrix... @abel

Answer (score 0):

i will see how far i can go.

we can write $$\frac{dh}{dt}=(x_1, x_2, x_3)^\top \times (h_1, h_2, h_3)^\top$$ in matrix notation as $$\frac{dh}{dt} = Ah, \text{ where  }  A = \pmatrix{0&-x_3&x_2\\x_3&0&-x_1\\-x_2&x_1&0} \text{ is a skew symmetric matrix.}$$

now, $$2h^\top Ah = 0 \implies 0=2h^\top \frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(h^\top h\right) \implies h^\top h = constant.\tag 1$$

we also have $$x^\top \frac{dh}{dt} = x^\top Ah = 0 \implies x^\top h= constant \tag 2$$

therefore $h$ represents a rotation about the axis $x.$  i don't know how to quantify the angle of rotation per unit of time. suppose we form a basis $B = \{x^\perp, x \},$  then with respect to this basis the transformation will have the form $$[h] = \pmatrix{\cos t & -\sin t&0\\\sin  t & \cos t & 0\\0&0&1}[h(0)] \text{ where } [h] \text{ represents the coordinates wrt } B.$$